# keycloak add server data to custom login page

Tags: keycloak, customization

I'm trying to implement logining through digital signature and on the login page I need data that generated every login attempt and which I will sign and send on server so I'm looking for way how to put server data on the login page which I will check on server after form submitted.

Flow not ended not much to see
but maybe there is a way to place authote to login page?

```
public class ExtAuthenticator extends UsernamePasswordForm {

private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ExtAuthenticatorclass);
private static final String LOGIN_FTL = "login-eds.ftl"; 

@Override
public void action(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    logger.infof("EDSAuthenticator action entry");
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
    if (!validateForm(context, formData)) {
        return;
    }

    KeycloakSession session = context.getSession();
    RealmModel realm = context.getRealm();
    UserModel user = session.users().getUserByUsername(realm, "user");
    context.setUser(user);
    context.success();
}

@Override
protected boolean validateForm(AuthenticationFlowContext context, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData) {
    logger.infof("EDSAuthenticator validateForm entry");
    logger.infof(context.getAuthenticationSession().getAuthNote("signdata"));
    formData.forEach((key, value) ->{
        System.out.println(key + ":" + value.size()) ;        
        System.out.println(key + ":" + value.toString());
        }
    );
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean requiresUser() {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected Response challenge(AuthenticationFlowContext context, MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData) {
    LoginFormsProvider forms = context.form(); 
     **//maybe there is a way to place this note to login page?**  
    context.getAuthenticationSession().setAuthNote("signdata", "signdatavalue");
    if (!formData.isEmpty()) forms.setFormData(formData);
    return forms.createForm(LOGIN_FTL);
}

@Override
protected Response createLoginForm(LoginFormsProvider form) {
    return form.createForm(LOGIN_FTL);
}

@Override
protected String getDefaultChallengeMessage(AuthenticationFlowContext context) {
    return Messages.INVALID_USERNAME;
}
}
```

login ftl FYI
there are some js scripts behind this form which work with cert

```
<#import "template.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.registrationLayout displayInfo=(realm.password && realm.registrationAllowed && !registrationDisabled??); section>
<#if section = "header">
    Enter
<#elseif section = "form">
    <div id="kc-form">
        <div id="kc-form-wrapper">
            <#if realm.password>
                <form id="kc-form-login" onsubmit="login.disabled = true; return true;" action="${url.loginAction}"
                      method="post">

                    <div class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}" style="display:none"> 
                        <label for="signedXML" class="${properties.kcLabelClass!}">signedXML</label>
                        <input id="signedXML" class="${properties.kcInputClass!}" value="signed xml test text" name="signedXML" type="hidden"/>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="kc-form-buttons" class="${properties.kcFormGroupClass!}">
                        <input tabindex="4"
                               class="${properties.kcButtonClass!} ${properties.kcButtonPrimaryClass!} ${properties.kcButtonBlockClass!} ${properties.kcButtonLargeClass!}"
                               name="login" id="kc-login" onClick="signXmlCall()" type="button" value="choose cert"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </#if>
        </div>
    </div>
</#if>

</@layout.registrationLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a way need to add forms.setAttribute("serverdata", dataforsign); then use serverdata in ftl like this ${serverdata}